# Leibniz integral rule for triple indefinite integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, indefinite-integrals

While trying to solve a problem involving vector potentials I ran into this type of function:
$$
f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z) + \int \frac\partial{\partial z} \left( \int \frac\partial{\partial y} \left( \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dz \right)dx \right)dy
$$

My primary question is if there's a way to simplify/evaluate the triple integral. Secondly, I was wondering if there's a name or theorem or any better way to describe this type of integral.

Thanks to anyone that's able to help.

Edit: Changed title to something that may be more relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be simplified, by interchanging the order of differentiation and integration. For the innermost integral,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\ dz=\int \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\ \partial x}\ dz,
$$
and doing the same once more yields that
$$
\int \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\ dz\ dx\ dy=\int\int\int \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial z\partial y\partial x}\ dz\ dx\ dy.
$$
Note also that $x,y,z$ can be reordered in any of the $3!$ desired orderings, in both the derivatives and in the integrals, each independently of the other, without affecting the value of the expression. (All this follows from [Leibniz' integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) and [equality of mixed partials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives), which require some technical analytical assumptions about the function $f(x,y,z)$ that are usually satisfied in practice.)

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question if you don't mind: Is there any way to further simplify the entire equation given that the function $ f $ is both equal to some function plus the triple integral of itself? What I'm really trying to do is get rid of the integral altogether.(Also, since you did answer the posted question I'd like to give you points, but the site won't let me without 15 reputation

Comment: Or if the function $ g $ has any restrictions for instance if $ g = g(x,y) $ is there a way to show that the integral evaluates to something trivial?

Comment: Sounds like you have a concrete situation in mind, might be better to post that instead of beating around the bush...